# Using PHP script to call json data and from database Grails do slow data fetch

Tags: php, javascript, grails

I am using php as my front end and grails as my back end. But it ruins my data fetch.

how can I increase the performance?

the php script is like this `/userdata.php` file

```
$uid=$_GET['uid'];
function getData($uid)

    {
        $dataUrl='http://localhost:8080/profile/user/teacher?id='.$uid;
        $json=file_get_contents($dataUrl);
        print_r($json);

    }
getData($uid);
```

javascript which calls this php script is

```
$.getJSON('userdata.php?uid'+1,function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: How it ruins you *data fetch* and which part of the script you want to increase performance.

Comment: the data call from php script on the tomcat server MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

This is so slow part:

```
$json=file_get_contents($dataUrl);
```

Try [сache](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php) this.